# Do multiple ground bus bars need to be tied on subpanel?

Tags: wiring, grounding, subpanel

I'm adding circuits to a subpanel.  For wiring neatness sake, I'm considering adding a second ground bus bar.  Do I need to tie both ground bars together (if so, what size wire), or is screwing them to the panel enclosure sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Depends, are we dealing with NEC, or Harper (that's me)'s Law?

NEC: The screws attaching the ground bar to the panel are fine if they are 32 thread pitch or finer (e.g. 8-32, 10-32, etc.)

I would also run a ground wire with the thickest wire you have on hand.

Comment: Another law???  OMG. +

Answer (score 1):

They should be properly linked.

Do **not** rely on the panel providing a reliable connection.

Comment: What is "properly linked" tho?  Jumper wire from bar to bar?  What size wire?  Do you need some special clip, etc...

Comment: @JPhi1618 size would depend on the size of the subpanel - so if you have that information...